# How can I access the commited file from a Subversion pre-commit hook in Perl?

Tags: perl, svn, pre-commit-hook

I need to do the following:

1. Write pre-commit hook in Perl
2. Hook should check all files being committed for presence of some text, and fail if that text is not found

**Basically, I need an example of Perl hook that reads files being committed.**

I am really looking for some elegant solution with the least amount of code.

Notes:
Hook should use `svnlook` or other better way to find files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pre-commit hook:

```
my $repos = shift;
my $txn = shift;

foreach my $line (`$svnlook changed -t $txn "$repos"`)
{
  chomp($line);
  if ($line !~ /^([AUD_]).\s\s(.+)$/)
  {
    print STDERR "Can't parse [$line].\n";
    exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
    my $action = $1;
    my $file = $2;
    chomp($file);
    #If path has trailing slash, then it is a folder and we want to skip folders
    if($file =~ /\/$/)
    {
    next;
    }
    my $fileContent = `$svnlook cat -t $txn "$repos" "$file"`;
    if ($action =~ /[AU]/)
    {
       my @lines = split(/\n/, $fileContent );
       #Check for whatever you need in this file's content

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first regex that includes [AUD] should be [AUD_]. Svnlook will start with an underscore when only properties are changed. These files should be skipped.  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.c.changed.html

Answer (score 0):

It should not be too difficult to modify [this example in Python](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/pre-commit-check.py) to do what you want. See also the `hooks` subdirectory of your repository for some templates and [hook scripts](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/) and [contributed hook scripts](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/pre-commit-check.py).

Comment: @Alex No problem. Editing others' posts is the way of Stackoverflow, and helps the site.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got the foundation figured out already:

- get list of all files being committed
- search each one of them in turn for particular text
- if text is found, reject commit

You'll find some information on writing pre-commit hooks in the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html).